# identifying that table header values are what they should be

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm trying to prove that in a table we have the following table labels. Date, amount, comment.

```
<table class="grid-table-body">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Amount (£)</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    .....
    .....
    .....

</tbody>
</table>
```

I've got as far as proving the table is present!

```
   var myTable = element(by.css('.grid-table-body'));
   expect(myTable.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
```

How can I loop through each `<th>` and get the text. If I was just to put them into an array I could prove they are what they should be. i.e.

```
expect(data.get(0).getText()).toBe("Date");
```

Would be enough (I think)

Comment: By the way, depending on how anal you want to be about the proof, `'.grid-table-body'` for an identifier is not enough. This only proves there is _an element_ with that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First locate the elements, then you can call `getText()`:

```
var headers = $$(".grid-table-body thead th");
expect(headers.getText()).toEqual(["Date", "Amount (£)", "Description"]);
```

To check that all of the headers are visible, you can either use:

```
expect(headers.isDisplayed()).toEqual([true, true, true]);
```

Or, check if there is no `false` in the array:

```
expect(headers.isDisplayed()).not.toContain(false);
```

You can also [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map)/[`reduce()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.reduce) it to a single boolean value.